# Objective C / Mac / Yosemite : Read smart card with new CryptoTokenKit API

Tags: objective-c, macos, smartcard

I am trying to read a smart card details with the new API released with yosemite (CryptoTokenKit).

I am able to get the name of the slot but the callback function to get the slot doesn't seem to return.

```
NSLog(@"START OF PROGRAM");
TKSmartCardSlotManager *manager = [TKSmartCardSlotManager defaultManager];

if(manager != NULL){

   NSArray *slots = [manager slotNames];

   if([slots count]>0){

        NSString *slotName = [slots objectAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"Slot Name : %@",slotName);

        [manager getSlotWithName:slotName reply:^(TKSmartCardSlot *slot) {
               NSLog(@"slot -- >%@",slot);
            }];
   }
   else{
        NSLog(@"no slots available");
   }

}else{
       NSLog(@"Card manager is null");
    }

 NSLog(@"END OF PROGRAM");
}
```

The result is as below,

```
#
2015-01-18 17:16:37.584 emiratesID-Coca[4449:31081] START OF PROGRAM
2015-01-18 17:16:37.588 emiratesID-Coca[4449:31081] Slot Name : OMNIKEY CardMan (076B:3021) 3021
2015-01-18 17:16:37.588 emiratesID-Coca[4449:31081] END OF PROGRAM
```

The callback block isnt getting called,am i missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you able to get access in to TKSmartCardSlotManager in test target. in my command line target i get access but in test target I get null. I have set the entitlements.plist properly in both. Is there any other reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently  the callback block is an asynchronous block hence in the above code - the program doesn't wait for the result and exists before the asynchronous block has finished its execution

A proper synchronization must be involved in order to let the main thread to wait for the asynchronous result. See the updated code below (marked a new for changes):

```
#
NSLog(@"START OF PROGRAM");


TKSmartCardSlotManager *manager = [TKSmartCardSlotManager defaultManager];

if(manager != NULL){

NSArray *slots = [manager slotNames];

if([slots count]>0){

    NSString *slotName = [slots objectAtIndex:0];


    NSLog(@"Slot Name : %@",slotName);

    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0); // NEW

    [manager getSlotWithName:slotName reply:^(TKSmartCardSlot *slot) {

        //<#code#>

        NSLog(@"slot instance ---  %d",[[slot makeSmartCard] valid]);

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema); // NEW


    }];


    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); // NEW

}else{

    NSLog(@"no slots available");

}


}else{
    NSLog(@"Card manager is null");
}

NSLog(@"END OF PROGRAM");

######
```

With the above code, the result as below -

```
#
   START OF PROGRAM
   Slot Name : OMNIKEY CardMan (076B:3021) 3021
   slot instance ---  <TKSmartCardSlot: 0x600000080140>
   END OF PROGRAM

#
```

Comment: Hi, did you able to send apdu command to the card. I have some problem, asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220795/osx-cryptotokenkit-smartcard-returned-error-6d00, let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see a "ctk: connection to slot registration server failed" in the console/your log by any chance ? (i.e. com.apple.security.smartcard' entitlement set to Boolean:YES).

Comment: No Error/exceptions - The entitlements is set to YES  - and  able to get the slot name.

The console output is as mentioned above. I expected the call back block to return instance of slot, but it isnt.

Though just to mention - if i pass an invalid slot name  to the 'getWithSlotName' -  the block get called and return null (as expected) .

Thanks for the help -