# OSX CryptoTokenKit SmartCard returned error 6d00

Tags: macos, smartcard, pcsc

I'm trying to read the master file of a smartcard on OSX using CryptoTokenKit but I always get statusword `6d00` as response. I also tried to run the [trivial example](https://github.com/dirkx/CryptoTokenKit-TrivialExample-OpenSC) with some modifications but get the same error. My reader is Gemalto PC Twin Reader.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion to fix it.

I'm using the following code:

```
    TKSmartCardSlot *slot = [self.smartCardManager slotWithName:slotName];
    TKSmartCard *card = [slot makeSmartCard];
    card.sensitive = YES;
    [card beginSessionWithReply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)  {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        NSLog(@"Proto: %ld", card.currentProtocol);
        NSData *data = [CommonUtil dataFromHexString:@"3F00"]; //<3f00>
        NSLog(@"%@", data);
        [card sendIns:0xA4 p1:0x00 p2:0x00 data:data le:@0
                reply:^(NSData *replyData, UInt16 sw, NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Response: %@", replyData);
             if (error) {
                 if (error.code == TKErrorCodeCommunicationError) {
                     // set response error code.
                 }
                 NSLog(@"%@", error);
             }
         }];
    }];
```

Comment: Karim, you added a new tag [tag:cryptotokenkit]. If you believe it's going to be of value to the community, please add the 'about' info for it. Otherwise, you could replace the tag on this question with a helpful cryptography-related tag that might get it the attention it deserves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is silly, but in the apdu where no response data is expected without the success code `90 00`, `le` should be `nil`.

```
[card sendIns:0xA4 p1:0x00 p2:0x00 data:nil le:nil
                reply:^(NSData *replyData, UInt16 sw, NSError *error)
         {
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Status Word 6D00 is " Instruction code not supported or invalid "
http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_5_basic_organizations.aspx

Not all the cards allow to select the Master File (0x3F00).